# Dart Print Map Array inside String

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart

I am trying to print my array element inside the string value but it prints the whole array.

```
var data = {'test' : 'hello '};
var name = "John";
print("$data['test']$name");
```

I am not able to find the right way to do this. Is there any other way in dart to concat array elements with variables or with static string values?

I have done in multiple languages like JS, JAVA or PHP but in dart, I am unable to find a way. Kindly guide what I am missing here.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? do you want to have a string 'hello' printed out?

Comment: I want to print array element inside string. Like above example should print "helloJohn". But its not working it prints like this "{'test' : 'hello '}John" currently

Comment: `print("${data['test']}$name")`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to perform *string interpolation*.

In dart, there are two types of string interpolation.

1. For variable

   You should use the `$variable` symbol to perform interpolation on a single variable.

   ```dart
   String name = 'Dart';
   print('Hello, $value'); // Hello, Dart
   ```
2. For expression

   You should use the `${expression}` to perform interpolation on an expression.

   ```dart
   int a=10,b=20;
   print('sum of $a + $b = ${a+b}'); // sum of 10 + 20 = 30
   ```

In your case, you can use

```dart
print('${data['test']}, $name'); // hello, john
```

You can check [dart docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings) for more information on string interpolation.